# mysql: how to resolve duplicate key errot

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, constraints, django-migrations

My django project has a migration that creates a foreign key on a table.  When the migrate command is executed, I receive a stacktrace with error :

> `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1061, "Duplicate key name "..."`

I located the key in table_constraints and in table_constraints_extensions.  It doesn't appear to be in any other constraint table.  There is one instance of the same key in each table.

The foreign key was created, and actually works, but the migration fails to complete due to duplicate keys.  I'm just not sure exactly where the duplication is because the FK constraint appears once in each of the tables mentioned above.

My project can function without doing anything further, but the migration process will be broken until I fix this in the db.

How and where do I fix this problem?

```
delete from table_constratins ...
alter table projects_project drop constraint ...
```

Comment: Enable General log and find the SQL text of the query which results in this error. Save the keyname which produces this error (or predict it using autonaming algo). Then check all existing constraints (index, UNIQUE, FK, CHECK, etc.) for the duplication.